# Downloading the HighCharts chart in Lightning Component

Tags: javascript, highcharts, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I would like to implement the Export Module of HighCharts in Lightning Components (Aura).

Can anyone help me how to implement this?

Any example with some sample code is helpful for me since I'm very new to this.

Comment: I understand you are trying to implement Highcharts export module, do you get any errors after this attempt?

Comment: It is working but the script is not getting loaded all the time. It is failed to load the script from Static Resources and unable to display the chart.

Comment: You need to describe more details for checking if it's problem with Highcharts export module.